# Assigning nil to generic optionals in Swift

Tags: ios, generics, swift

I've created a simple generic grid data structure in Swift as follows. Basically it creates an Array of optionals with type T? and initialises the array with with nil. But when I try to explicitly set one grid element back to nil the compiler complains with something I don't really understand.

```
struct Grid<T> {
    let columns: Int, rows: Int
    var grid: [T?]
    init(columns: Int, rows: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        grid = Array(count: rows * columns, repeatedValue: nil)
    }

    func test() {
        grid[0] = nil
    }
}
```

Compiler's outcry when test() function is added:

```
Grid.swift:26:13: '@lvalue $T7' is not identical to 'T?'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The `test()` method modifies the value of a property
in the structure, therefore you have to mark it as "mutating":

```
struct Grid<T> {
    // ...

    mutating func test() {
        grid[0] = nil
    }
}
```

See [Modifying Value Types from Within Instance Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html) in the Swift book:

> **Modifying Value Types from Within Instance Methods**
>
> Structures and enumerations are *value types*. By default, the
>   properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance
>   methods.
>
> However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or
>   enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to *mutating*
>   behavior for that method. ...